# using different images in different sections

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to figure out how I can have different images on these sections i've created.

You can view the demo [here.](http://codepen.io/Conscious/pen/brIem/)

Right now it has the sames images on all the sections. I've tried using `.order-header:nth-child(x)` and then changing the `background: url()` but nothing happens.

Is there any way i can add different images to these sections without adding any image tag in the html code?

Here is the code I have:

HTML:

```
   <div id="order-info">
      <div class="order-column">
        <span class="order-header">Fast and free delivery</span>
        <p class="order-content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
        <a class="order-links" href="international-shipping.html">See our Shipping Methods..</a>
      </div>

      <div class="order-column">
        <span class="order-header">Free returns within <br>14 days</span>
        <p class="order-content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
        <a class="order-links" href="returns-refunds.html">Read more about our <br>Return Policy..</a>
      </div>

      <div class="order-column">
        <span class="order-header">Secure <br>payment methods</span>
        <p class="order-content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s..</p>
        <a class="order-links" href="international-shipping.html">Read more about our <br>Payment Methods..</a>
      </div>

      <div class="order-column">
        <span class="order-header">Customer Feedback</span>
        <p class="order-content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
        <a class="order-links" href="international-shipping.html">Read more..</a>
      </div>

      <div class="order-column">
        <span class="order-header">Secure e-commerce</span>
        <p class="order-content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
        <a class="order-links" href="international-shipping.html">Read more about <br>secure e-commerce</a>
      </div>

    </div>
```

CSS

```
    #order-info {
      margin-top: 20px;
      margin-left: 10px;
      position: absolute;
      width: 1004px;
      height: 250px;
      background: #fff;
    }

    .order-column:nth-child(1) { float: left; }
    .order-column:nth-child(2) { float: left; padding-left: 20px; }
    .order-column:nth-child(3) { float: left; padding-left: 20px; }
    .order-column:nth-child(4) { float: left; padding-left: 20px; }
    .order-column:nth-child(5) { float: left; padding-left: 20px; }

    .order-header {
      padding: 45px 10px 0 10px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      font-weight: bold;
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: left;
      white-space: nowrap;
      position: relative;
      font-size: 13px;
      background: url("images/fast-and-free-delivery.png") no-repeat top center;
    }



    .order-content {
      color: #888;
      font-size: 12px;
      padding-top: 10px;
      line-height: 15px;
      padding-left: 10px;
      padding-right: 24px;
      width: 150px;
    }

    .order-links {
      font-size: 12px;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #2793e6;
      line-height: 15px;
      float: left;
      display: inline;
      padding: 13px 10px;
    }

    .order-links:hover {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `!important` to override the default background on your `.order-header:nth-child(x)` classes like so.

```
.order-column:nth-child(1) .order-header{
    background: url("some url") !important;
}

.order-column:nth-child(2) .order-header{
  background: url("some other url") !important;
}
```

Comment: if i use this code all the images changes and not one specific image

Comment: @Nohman Ah, I didn't notice that in your html structure.. See my edited answer and working code pen. :) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mFjoh

Comment: The !important tag isn't necessary in your example.

Answer (score 0):

For each div, you need put a background, if you want change it, in CSS of course.
like you have already do

```
.order-header {
      padding: 45px 10px 0 10px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      font-weight: bold;
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: left;
      white-space: nowrap;
      position: relative;
      font-size: 13px;
      background: url("images/fast-and-free-delivery.png") no-repeat top center;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just making different class in each ? order-header-1, order-header-2, order-header-3..
Then in you css you insert individually each background (img link)

Comment: that's what I thought about, but i needed to know if there is any way I can use `nth-child`

Comment: I guess it's the only way, I'm not sure, or you add tags in your html like this http://jsfiddle.net/demchak_alex/7mUDG/2/